# How can I commit to an old git tag?

Tags: git, github, git-svn

So two months ago I migrated our codebase in SVN into Git with the complete changeset history. Immediately after that, we tagged a new release and continued working. So while we've continued working in the new tag, some people have continued fixing bugs in the old tag in SVN and now I'd like to pull all those changes into that tag in Git.

I can clone the tag and make Git will let me make commits into it, but I can't push anything back up with git-push. Checking git-log, the commit is there but git-st tells me that I'm not currently on any branch.

So Internet, how can I commit to an old git tag?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tags are not movable.  Once you have created a tag that points to a particular commit, you cannot change that tag later.

It sounds like you meant to create a branch instead.  You should create a new branch (`git branch branchname && git checkout branchname`) to make sure you don't lose your commits.  Then push that branch to the repository and have your release/bugfixing developers work in that branch for the release.

Comment: A combination of branching and overriding old tags is what I was looking for since this is tag is mirrored code from our SVN repo.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't really override old tags.  But you can abandon them.  :)

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm ending up doing. Such a pain in the ass to get all these old commits back in. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Oh, by abandon them I meant just forget about them... are you actually rebuilding the repo from SVN without them?

Comment: tags are removable, you can do: git tag -d <tag>, but on the remote, you have to remove it too before you can do another tag sync: git push origin --tags

Comment: @linehrr This is not advisable once a tag has been pushed; anyone who has cloned the repository will be very sad when they try to fetch.

Answer (score 74):

If someone is coming here after searching for "replace git tag" or something similar, I recommend the following approach:

```
git tag -d <tagname>
git checkout <new commit or branch>
git tag -a <tagname>
git push <remotename> <tagname> -f
```

for example:

```
git checkout 2.0
git tag -d v2.0
git tag -a v2.0 -m"Version 2.0"
git push origin v2.0 -f
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: the last command can also be:    git push <remote_name> <tag_name> -f     e.g.    git push origin v2.0 -f

Answer (score 11):

You mean branch, not tag. Tags in Git are point-in-time bookmarks in your master branch. While you CAN overwrite a tag (`git tag -f`), it is not recommended. I will ONLY overwrite a tag if it has not been deployed yet.

Answer (score 9):

If user is using same branch from which user created the old tag then first create new changelist. otherwise checkout the tag and then create new changelist. then use below steps to update existing tag with new changelist number

`git tag -f <old tag name>`

`git push -f --tags`

Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
 + ... `<old tag name>` -> `<old tag name>` (forced update)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, you need to create a branch where your commits are. To do this, check out the version you want to push up. In your git bash, type in:

```
git branch old-version
```

This should create a branch at the location of your commit called `old-version`. Then try pushing.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new branch at the position of the tag, delete the tag, make your commits, recreate the tag and push.

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of things going on here.

1. It sounds like you don't have an adequate understanding of the purpose of [git tag](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-tag.html).  I'd recommend reading that [man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-tag.html) and also the [relevant section](http://progit.org/book/ch2-10.html) of [Pro Git](http://progit.org/).  [Pro Git](http://progit.org/) also makes an excellent introduction in general to the tool, as well as [Git Magic](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~blynn/gitmagic/).
2. As pointed out by others, you either already created a branch and are committing on it and just mistakenly identified it as a tag here, or you actually created a tag and have been committing new commits outside of a branch and that's pretty confusing.  You definitely want to read up on [git branch](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html) to get a feel for how to use that if you don't already know.
3. It sounds like you and your team could use a work flow that supports multiple streams of release, maintenance, and development and for that I would humbly suggest this [most excellent guide from Vincent Driessen](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).  I introduced this with my team at my last employer and it changed the way we worked.  Reading that should give you an incredibly good understanding of how git can best support the way it sounds like your team may already be trying to work.
4. There is no way to commit to an old tag directly.  As pointed out by others, a tag is nothing but a name for a specific commit.  However, I have a few thoughts here that may be of service to you.

   1. You can always check out a branch based on a tag via `git checkout -b my-new-branch name-of-tag`.  This will give you brand new branch based on that tag that you can then commit into.  Sharing that branch becomes as simple as pushing it out to a public touch point and letting others pull it down.
   2. If you want a moving tag, you're doing something 'insane' (at least in the minds of the writers of [git tag](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-tag.html)s man page.  They are partly right, in that moving tags are really just branch heads and thus can simply be a branch.  Tags are not meant to be part of that story.  If you really desire a moving tag, though, you can accomplish that by jumping through several flaming hoops and making the leap over the dagger pit by following the instruction found in the [Re-Tagging Section](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-tag.html) of the `git tag` man page.

Comment: Here's a working link to the git tag page: http://schacon.github.com/git/git-tag.html